# iterating json file with pure javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, loops

I have a problem with iterating `json` response.
I'm creating ajax function with GET method and url to json file
when I log `ajax.response`, I get this :

```
        "
300x250.js:120 {
300x250.js:120 \
300x250.js:120 r
300x250.js:120 \
300x250.js:120 n
300x250.js:120 \
300x250.js:120 t
300x250.js:120 \
300x250.js:120 "
300x250.js:120 l
300x250.js:120 a
300x250.js:120 n
300x250.js:120 g
300x250.js:120 \
300x250.js:120 "
```

1. how can I escape `\r` `\n` and `\t`
2. this is the actual code hardcoded in the `300x250.js`

File content:

```
var feed = {
    looping: 2,
    target: "_blank",
    bbttext: "Tap to bet",
    text21: "bet &pound;10&nbsp;",
    text22: "get &pound;30 free"
};
```

I have to use ajax to get these values from .json file but i get the upper response and i want to populate var feed with `ajax.responseText`.

And also I apologise for not so good english and not so good explained problem

Comment: What did you try ? From what I understand you are reading a text file and not deserializing a json object.

Comment: i tried almost everything.
ajax.open('get', 'jsonfeed_test.json', true);
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
     //console.log(JSON.parse(ajax.responseText));
     a = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
     for(var prop in a){
      if(a.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
       //console.log(prop + ': ' + a[prop]);
       //console.log(prop);
        var key = prop;
        var val = a[prop];
       //console.log(val);
       //console.log(a[prop]);
       feed = {
        key: val
       };
       console.log(feed);
      }
     }
   }
  }

Comment: That isn't a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file content is not pure JSON. A JSON file looks like the following :

```
{
    looping: 2,
    target: "_blank",
    bbttext: "Tap to bet",
    text21: "bet &pound;10&nbsp;",
    text22: "get &pound;30 free"
}
```

Once your file is pure JSON, you can use XMLHttpRequest :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "300x250.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myJSONObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: well...im not very familiar with JSON.This task is given to me for job hiring and they use GreenSock.One of conditions is to use ajax to fetch the data and i cant use jQuery.Can you gave me some ideas or alternatives how to populate that variable "feeds" with responseText from the json file? damn i have so many questions :D thanks a lot for answering :)

Comment: Edited the answer with a pure Javascript solution.